# How can I overlay one image onto another?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, image-processing, overlay

I would like to display an image composed of **two** images.

I want image **rectangle.png** to show with image **sticker.png** on **top** of it with its **left-hand** corner at pixel 10, 10.

Here is as far as I got, but **how do I combine the images?**

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\test\rectangle.png"));
image.Stretch = Stretch.None;
image.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

Image imageSticker = new Image();
imageSticker.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\test\sticker.png"));

image.OverlayImage(imageSticker, 10, 10); //how to do this?

TheContent.Content = image;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a Panel to add both Image controls to.  A Grid or Canvas will allow this, but I would go with the Grid as it will constrain the Image controls (thereby stretching or shrinking them as appropriate).

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\test\rectangle.png"));
image.Stretch = Stretch.None;
image.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

Image imageSticker = new Image();
imageSticker.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\test\sticker.png"));
imageStiker.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);

Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Children.Add(image);
grid.Children.Add(imageSticker);

TheContent.Content = grid;
```

Comment: excellent, this is the approach I used, just needed to also add a imageSticker.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;

Comment: This is not real overlay. What if I wanted to use the combined image on a button? This wouldnt work.

Comment: Why not? The Button can definitely have that grid as its content.

Answer (score 2):

You can just put one Image control over the top of the other Image control in your View.  Place both into a Grid or Canvas, and just overlay one of the images on top of the other.  This also lets you using opacity to do blending, and works very well.

If you need to get them into the same image, there are a couple of options....

You could make a [WritableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) out of the first image, then manually "paint" the other image pixels on top of the first one.  This then can act as an image source for your image in the display.

Alternatively, you could do the overlay I mentioned above, and render this into a [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx).  This could then be used as your image source.