# c# winforms usercontrol - cannot create System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I am trying to create an image in memory so that I can combine two or more transparent images and present them as a bitmap in a picture box in a user control.

my opening code :

```
System.Drawing.Image Beat = new System.Drawing.Image()
```

results in 
 "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Drawing.Image'"

can anyone tell me why?

I am using the following directives (so to rule out ambiguity)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
```

many thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Image` is abstract, just as the compiler informed you. You need to choose a "concrete" implementation of Image, like `Bitmap`.

Comment: Thanks and Sorry, was referencing code posted on this site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479133/how-can-i-overlay-one-image-onto-another ... on closer inspection this is a WPF example so I can assume it is different for winforms?

Comment: WPF doesn't use System.Drawing.dll, it would be `BitmapSource` in WPF (I believe, I'm not a WPF expert). WinForms uses System.Drawing.dll where `Bitmap` can be found.

Comment: Ok, I am going to assume that the link I posted above only works on WPF and that in WPF you can create an Image in the manner described but that in WinForms I have to use Bitmap instead.  all of this in the spirit of trying to get real image layers and transparency working! ;-)

thanks for your help

D

Answer (score 1):

[System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) is an abstract class which means it cannot be instantiated. You need to create an instance of a concrete class that derives from it, like [System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) or [System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.metafile.aspx).